# Where can I access the original, Satoshi written Bitcoin code?

Tags: bitcoin-core, history, satoshi-nakamoto

The articles of https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=41718.0 seem to be annotated walkthroughs, and I'd like to see the raw code, as it was originally written in the first release.

Comment: This claims to preserve it without source: https://github.com/trottier/original-bitcoin

Answer (score 33, accepted):

The Bitcoin client has been hosted on GitHub for a while now. It's very close to what Satoshi initially wrote. Here's the first commit dated back to 2009: https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/tree/4405b78d6059e536c36974088a8ed4d9f0f29898

You could also browse all the commits from way back: https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/commits/master?page=151

Some other research points me to the actual first email sent to the cryptography mailing-list by Satoshi where he actually delivered the 0.1 version: http://www.metzdowd.com/pipermail/cryptography/2009-January/014994.html

Here's the direct link provided by Satoshi but it doesn't seem to work anymore: http://downloads.sourceforge.net/bitcoin/bitcoin-0.1.0.rar

Googling a bit I found this, which is what you're looking for: https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=68121.0

Comment: So earliest on github is - https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/tree/v0.1.5

Answer (score 8):

This page contains files for the first three available Bitcoin codebases written by Satoshi Nakamoto.

http://satoshi.nakamotoinstitute.org/code/

Answer (score 6):

Here is the first version uploaded to sourceforge:
https://sourceforge.net/p/bitcoin/code/1/tree//trunk/

Comment: As it indicates, they has been added by Martti Malmi (2nd bitcoin developer), Its not added by SN.

Comment: We are developers & we'd better speak **accurately**. I've always been grateful when someone has helped me correct myself by giving hints. I didn't intend bothering you, so I guess you'd better consult [Code of conduct](https://meta.stackexchange.com/conduct) one more time. Thanks in advance.